# Solving differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation

```
DSolve[y''[x] == (λ y[x])/Sqrt[-1 + x], y[x],x]
```

But do not know how to actually solve it. Any suggestion?

Comment: I suspect you need to do this numerically. Do you have some reason to expect an analytic solution?

Comment: Are you have any answer to numerical solution?

Comment: Basically the same, use `NDSolve` and you need to specify `lambda` and provide initial/boundary conditions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Mathematica* can also solve this differential equation if you help it with the choice of variable substitution:

```
Clear[y,λ,x,z,u,v]
eqn = y''[x] == λ y[x]/Sqrt[-1 + x]
(* ==> (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == (λ y[x])/Sqrt[-1 + x] *)

u[x_] := Sqrt[x - 1]
y[x_] := z[u[x]]
eqn2 = Simplify[eqn /. x -> InverseFunction[u][v], v > 0]
(*
==> 4 v^2 λ z[v] + Derivative[1][z][v] == 
 v (z^\[Prime]\[Prime])[v]
*)

zSolution[v_] = z[v] /. First[DSolve[eqn2, z[v], v]]
(*
==> AiryAiPrime[2^(2/3) v λ^(1/3)] C[1] + 
 AiryBiPrime[2^(2/3) v λ^(1/3)] C[2]
*)

ySolution[x_] = zSolution[u[x]]
(*
==> AiryAiPrime[2^(2/3) Sqrt[-1 + x] λ^(1/3)] C[1] + 
 AiryBiPrime[2^(2/3) Sqrt[-1 + x] λ^(1/3)] C[2]
*)

Block[{y}, Simplify[eqn /. y -> ySolution]]
(* ==> True *)
```

All I did here was to define a new function `z` through the substitution of variable $u = \sqrt{x-1}$. The original differential equation `eqn` is then transformed into the new one, `eqn2`, which can be solved analytically with `DSolve`. Finally, I also check that the general solution obeys the original equation when substituting back the original independent variable `x`.

**Edit: an alternate substitution**

To get Bessel functions as solutions, instead of derivatives of Airy functions, the only change to the above would be to choose as our new variable $u = (x-1)^{(3/4)}$. This is shown here by repeating the same steps as before with that single change:

```
Clear[y, λ, x, z, u, v]
eqn = y''[x] == λ y[x]/Sqrt[-1 + x];
u[x_] := (x - 1)^(3/4)
y[x_] := z[u[x]]
eqn2 = Simplify[eqn /. x -> InverseFunction[u][v], v > 0];
zSolution[v_] = z[v] /. First[DSolve[eqn2, z[v], v]];
ySolution[x_] = zSolution[u[x]];   
Block[{y = ySolution}, FullSimplify[eqn]]
(* ==> True *)

TeXForm[ySolution[x]]
```

> $$c_1 \sqrt{x-1}
>    J_{\frac{2}{3}}\left(-\frac{4}{3
>    } i (x-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{\lambda
>    }\right)+c_2 \sqrt{x-1}
>    Y_{\frac{2}{3}}\left(-\frac{4}{3
>    } i (x-1)^{3/4} \sqrt{\lambda
>    }\right)$$

This is an alternate general solution.

Comment: Are there any answer for following equation?                                          y''[x] == λ x y[x]/Sqrt[-1 + x]

Comment: Yes, my first approach does yield a solution in the form of a `DifferentialRoot`, which means you have a solution but it can't be expressed in terms of special functions. So you then have a solution for `ySolution` that can only be evaluated when you give numerical values to the parameters. The integration constants in that `DifferentialRoot` can in principle also be eliminated by adding two boundary conditions to `eqn2`, e.g. like this: `DSolve[eqn2&&z[1]==1&&z'[1]==1,z[v],v]`. The result still needs a numerical value for $\lambda$, though.

Comment: Dear Dr Jens, Many thanks.

Comment: Dear Dr Jens, why after change this equation to eqn = y''[x] == \[Lambda]*x^(3/4)* y[x]/Sqrt[1 - x] with 0<x<1, I can not solve it? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/86302/solving-differential-equation-analytical-or-numerical

Answer (score 5):

A simpler direct solution is the following:

Ignoring the -1 for a moment, i.e. replacing Sqrt[x-1] by Sqrt[x], Mathematica  solves the resulting ODE easily

```
sol = DSolve[z''[x] == \[Lambda] z[x]/Sqrt[x], z[x], x]

(*
Out[1]= {{z[x] -> (2/3)^(2/3) Sqrt[x] \[Lambda]^(1/3)
      BesselI[-(2/3), 4/3 x^(3/4) Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] C[1] Gamma[1/3] + ((-2)^(
     2/3) Sqrt[x] \[Lambda]^(1/3)
      BesselI[2/3, 4/3 x^(3/4) Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] C[2] Gamma[5/3])/3^(2/3)}}
*)
```

Now we restore the -1 and get

```
y[x_] = z[x] /. sol[[1]] /. x -> x - 1

(*
Out[2]= (2/3)^(2/3) Sqrt[-1 + x] \[Lambda]^(1/3)
   BesselI[-(2/3), 4/3 (-1 + x)^(3/4) Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] C[1] Gamma[1/
   3] + ((-2)^(2/3) Sqrt[-1 + x] \[Lambda]^(1/3)
   BesselI[2/3, 4/3 (-1 + x)^(3/4) Sqrt[\[Lambda]]] C[2] Gamma[5/3])/3^(2/3)
*)
```

Finally we check that y[x] really solves the original ODE

```
y''[x]/(\[Lambda] y[x]) // FullSimplify

(*
Out[3]= 1/Sqrt[-1 + x]
*)
```

Check ok. Done.

Answer (score 3):

This is a Bessel type ODE. So it has solutions in terms of special Bessel functions. This can be done by hand using `Frobenius` series method if needed. You might want to do this to verify the solution below.

Here is the solution from Maple and I converted it to Mathematica syntax. The solution contains 2 arbitrary constants of integrations and use `BesselI` and `BesselY` both implemented in Mathematica. So direct translation was only needed

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Translate to Mathematica:

```
Clear[x, c1, c2, lam]
sol1 = Sqrt[x - 1] BesselJ[2/3, 4/3 Sqrt[-lam] (x - 1)^(3/4)];
sol2 = Sqrt[x - 1] BesselY[2/3, 4/3 Sqrt[-lam] (x - 1)^(3/4)];
fullSolution = c1 sol1 + c2 sol2
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Are there any solution for following differential equation with Maple?                       y''[x] =x  λ y[x]/Sqrt[-1 + x];

Answer (score 1):

for reference here is the direct numerical approach. Obviously you need to specify lambda and initial conditions and a domain.

```
 \[Lambda] = 1;
 x0 = 1 + 1*^-4;
 x1 = 4;
 ySolution[x_] = y[x] /. First@NDSolve[y''[x] == (\[Lambda] y[x])/
   Sqrt[-1 + x] && y[x0] == 0 && y'[x0] == 1 , y[x],
      {x, x0, x1}]
 Plot[ySolution[x], {x, x0, x1}]
```

I just guessed `x==1` is an important point.  The equation has a singularity but the solution is well behaved at `x==1` , which we can see by setting an initial condition at some small epsilon.

[image]

aside, here is how you match those initial conditions using Dr WH analytic solution:

```
 \[Lambda] = 1
 sol = DSolve[z''[x] == \[Lambda] z[x]/Sqrt[x], z[x], x];
 y[x_] = z[x] /. sol[[1]] /. x -> x - 1 

 Limit[y[x], x -> 1] -> C[1]  (* so C[1] must be zero *)
```

some handwaving later we find:

```
 C[2] -> real * (1+I Sqrt[3] )
```

produces a real solution that we can differentiate to match the `y'[1]` condition.. sol we have:

```
 yprime1=1
 ySolution[x_] = 
    y[x] /. {C[1] -> 0 , 
     C[2] -> - yprime1 Gamma[2/3]/Gamma[5/3]/2/(2/3)^(1/3) (1 + I Sqrt[3])}

 Plot[ySolution[x], {x, 1, 4}]
```

> (* same plot *)

Comment: My differential equation is:                                                                                                        ode = (\[Lambda]*(x)*y[x])/Sqrt[1 - x] + Derivative[2][y][x] == 0
ic = {y[1] == 0, y'[1] == 1}
DSolve[{ode, ic}, y[x], x]                                                                                                              and my disatnce is on [0,1]

Comment: and I need y(x).