# Using DSolve to find y[x] for a second-order differential equation

Tags: differential-equations

Excuse me can you help me on solving the following differential equation by Mathematica ?!

$$d^2y[x]/dx^2-(1/(x+a))*dy[x]/dx+(m*x+L)y[x]=0$$

i had try on it as following :

```
ode=D[y[x],{x,2}]-1/(x+a)*D[y[x],x]+(m*x+L)*y[x]==0
DSolve[ode,y[x],x]
```

it gives me strange output :

```
{{y[x] -> DifferentialRoot[Function[{\[FormalY], \[FormalX]}, 
      {(\[FormalX] + a)*(L + \[FormalX]*m)*\[FormalY][\[FormalX]] - 
         Derivative[1][\[FormalY]][\[FormalX]] + 
         (\[FormalX] + a)*Derivative[2][\[FormalY]][
           \[FormalX]] == 0, \[FormalY][0] == C[1], 
       Derivative[1][\[FormalY]][0] == C[2]}]][x]}}
```

Comment: Related: [(65169)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/65169), [(81375)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/81375)

Comment: Have you looked up `DifferentialRoot` in the documentation? It usually means `DSolve` could not put the solution in terms of elementary functions or standard special functions.

Comment: yes , i saw it ,,, but i need another way to solve this equation ?? how can i solve it ??? what command should i use?

Answer (score 5):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use a numeric technique.

First, include some arbitrary initial conditions.

```
ode = {D[y[x], {x, 2}] - 1/(x + a)*D[y[x], x] + (m*x + L)*y[x] == 0, 
   y[0] == y0, y'[0] == yp0};

sol = ParametricNDSolve[ode, y, {x, -5, 5}, {m, a, L, y0, yp0}];

Manipulate[
 Plot[y[m, a, L, y0, yp0][x] /. sol, {x, -5, 5}],
 {{m, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{a, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{L, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y0, 0}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{yp0, 1}, -5, 5, 0.1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

An analytic solution may be available for specific values of the parameters. For example,

```
ode2 = ode /. {m -> 1, a -> 1, L -> 1, y0 -> 0, yp0 -> 1}

(* {(1 + x) y[x] - Derivative[1][y][x]/(1 + x) + (y^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == 0, 
 y[0] == 0, Derivative[1][y][0] == 1} *)

sol2 = DSolve[ode2, y, x][[1]]

(* {y -> Function[{x}, -(((-1)^(
        1/3) (AiryAiPrime[(-1)^(1/3) + (-1)^(1/3) x] AiryBiPrime[(-1)^(1/3)] -
           AiryAiPrime[(-1)^(
            1/3)] AiryBiPrime[(-1)^(
             1/3) + (-1)^(1/3) x]))/(-AiryAiPrime[(-1)^(1/3)] AiryBi[(-1)^(
          1/3)] + AiryAi[(-1)^(1/3)] AiryBiPrime[(-1)^(1/3)]))]} *)
```

Verifying the solution

```
ode2 /. sol2 // Simplify

(* {True, True, True} *)

Plot[y[x] /. sol2, {x, -5, 5},
 PlotPoints -> 50, MaxRecursion -> 5,
 WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks , but you mean that this differential equation does not have solution except when m=1,L=1,a=1<y0=0 and yp0=1 ???

Comment: No, I said that analytic solutions **may** be available and that `{m -> 1, a -> 1, L -> 1, y0 -> 0, yp0 -> 1}` is an **example**. There **may** be other cases with an analytic solution. There are numerous case with a numeric solution as shown in the `Manipulate`.

Comment: yes i saw this , but i need a general solution ,, How can i get it please ?

Comment: If Mathematica gives you a `DifferentialRoot` solution, it means it couldn't find anything better and that a general analytic solution in all likelihood doesn't exist.