# Partial differential equation with infinity limit

Tags: differential-equations, boundary-condition-at-infinity

How do I get *Mathematica* to solve the following partial differential equation

$$ \frac{\partial u(y,t)}{\partial t} = \nu \frac{\partial^2 u(y,t)}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial U_0(t)}{\partial t}$$

where $U_0 = U_{0m} \cdot sech(\frac{2 \pi}{T} (t-T))$, 
$(T,U_{0m})$=constant

with the following boundary conditions:

$$ u=0 \; {\rm for} \; y = 0 $$ $$ u=U_0 \; {\rm for} \;y \rightarrow \infty$$

Have tried

```
U0[t_] := U0m Sech[2 π/T (t - T)];
eq = D[u[y, t], t] == nu D[D[u[y, t], y], y] - D[U0[t], t];
DSolve[
    {eq, u[0, t] == 0, limit[u[y, t], y -> Infinity] == U0[t]},
    u[y, t],
    {y, t}
]
```

Comment: Do you expect there to be an analytic solution to this equation? Second: `limit` should be `Limit`, but I'm not aware that `DSolve` supports that as a boundary condition (but perhaps it's so).

Comment: Is it `- D[U0[t], t]` or `+ D[U0[t], t]`? And where's the initial condition ($u(y,0)=?$)?

Answer (score 3):

I tried solving the equation with `DSolve` by disregarding boundary conditions, but couldn't get an analytic solution. So I think the specific equation is not solvable, which only leaves the question of how to impose a boundary conditions at infinity. This can be done by doing the transformation of variables

$$y = \tan(x)$$

All I can do with this here is to show how it's used in principle, since the actual problem doesn't yield to a symbolic treatment.

Without the boundary condition at infinity, the equation has the following general form after making the transformation of variables to the new equation `eqX`:

```
U0[t_] := U0m Sech[2 Pi/T (t - T)];
eq = D[u[y, t], t] == nu D[D[u[y, t], y], y] - D[U0[t], t];

eqX = 
 Simplify[eq /. u -> (ψ[ArcTan[#], #2] &) /. y -> Tan[x], Pi/2 > x > 0]
```

> $$\nu  \cos ^4(x) \psi ^{(2,0)}(x,t)+\frac{2 \pi  \text{U0m}
>    \tanh \left(\frac{2 \pi  (t-T)}{T}\right)
>    \text{sech}\left(\frac{2 \pi  (t-T)}{T}\right)}{T}\\=2 \nu
> \sin (x) \cos ^3(x) \psi ^{(1,0)}(x,t)+\psi
>    ^{(0,1)}(x,t)$$

The purpose of the transformation of variables is that it allows us to replace $y\to \infty$ by $x\to \pi/2$ in the next steps of the calculation. Then a boundary specification would look like `ψ[Pi/2, t] == ...`. However, we can't go further in this case:

```
DSolve[eqX, ψ[x, t], {x, t}])
```

> no solution

To see a more successful application of the same idea, see for example [Solving differential equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/79443/245)